# Blazor Server Forces User to Reauthenticate on IIS Recycle / Application Deploy

Tags: authentication, iis, blazor-server-side

I started a blazor server project, with the default identity (local account, I think). Allows you to use scaffolding items to edit the identity pages.

Everytime I deploy out an update to IIS, I'm logged out of my application. I would think my bearer token or cookie would still be valid and reestablish a connection no problem.

Every deploy most likely causes an app pool recycle, maybe not since I don't update the web.config.

Anyways, anyone with information on how to keep the token/cookie alive during blazor server deployments would be greatly appreciated. I wasn't finding much luck on the internet.

Googling for answers. Tried looking at identity code to see why this may be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by forgetting to configure a secret-store or key-vault for the server-side code to persist private-keys and other cryptographic details to - which means every time it starts-up it has to re-generate a new set of secrets/private-keys, which invalidate all previously-issued public-keys and signatures.

I'm not a Blazor user so I don't know if Blazor itself requires anything special, but in ASP.NET Core you just need to call `AddDataProtection` during `ConfigureServices` and then invoke a *data protection* implementation on the returned `IDataProtectionBuilder`, such as:

- `PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage`
- `ProtectKeysWithCertificate`
- `PersistKeysToFileSystem`

Comment: This seems be to working with an application pool recycle! Thank you, I'll mark it as answered when I try deploying an update out later today and get the same result, which is what I expect.

I did end up using a different implementation of PersistKeysToDbContext since Blazor uses EF Core out of the box.

Comment: Seems to have fixed it for app recycles but not for an actual deployment. I am currently doing a clean deploy to a secondary directory then switching IIS over to that new folder. This is due to Blazor locking the main dll and not having web deploy setup yet. Any other ideas; I'm going to try later a deploy to the same folder vs a new one but I wouldn't see why that should solve anything.

Comment: My guess is that your deployment process is nuking the directory or storage location where secrets are being stored.

Comment: So your solution fixed the problem with IIS Recycles; therefore I am marking it as a solution. I did determine that as long as I don't change directories; I stay logged in. Blazor has a unfortunate habit of locking the main DLL, so definitely my next task but you solved it so thank you!